# How to log the error info in Eclipse when develop a python and django web project

Tags: django, eclipse

i do not know how to output the log info in Eclipse when i develop a python + django web project.For instant,i want to check one special variable in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you wish to log to eclipse? How about installing PyDev, running the server in --noreload with the debugger mode and set a breakpoint. you can even set a watch that will trigger if the value changes.

Comment: i have add PyDev into my Eclipse,but i want to see some special variable in console.So how to check breakpoint.3Q

Comment: yeah, just `print >> sys.sterr, myvar` will print the variable out into the eclipse console in red.

Answer (score 0):

print >> sys.stderr, 'My debug msg' should work (provided you run with the --noreloa parameter).

Note that if you right click your django project you can do a "run as > django" and it'll create a run configuration with that already. Take a look at: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_django.html to see how to properly.